# CSS link not loading in Angular 2 in case of displaying static HTML

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular2-template

I have an HTML page which I want to display in Angular 2 component as it is. That HTML page consists of CSS links also.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="..../dummy.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Some dummy Heading</h1>
        <h2>Second line</h2>
        <h3>Third line</h3>
        <div>
            <img height="300px" width="400px" src="Lighthouse.jpg" alt="Can not load an image :/">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have displayed HTML using this -

```
this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
```

Using above I am successfully able to display content of HTML in my component. But my CSS is not getting applied (nor it's getting called - checked in Network tab of browser).

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions.

Comment: `"..../dummy.css"` is not a valid Path. - OP : "But it's not the actual path I use, it's just for the example" - Me : "Give us the actual path you use, then"

Comment: This is the actual path - http://localhost:3002/dummycourse.css

Comment: So your actual line of code is `<link rel="stylesheet" href="localhost:3002/dummycourse.css">` ?

Comment: Yes. And it works perfectly fine when I display in ReactJS using dangerouslySetInnerHTML. CSS gets loaded and applied on my HTML.

Comment: I don't know, then. It depends on your back-end. But we never write "localhost:port" in a resource URL, it's always a relative path. Then, it depends what back-end you use and how its routes are configured to serve assets.

Comment: just for your reference - when I open my HTML in any browser, it works perfectly fine - (loads CSS, applies it and etc.) I do not have any backend for now. I just used `serve` do deploy my HTML. I am pretty sure CSS path is not the issue here.